# Compiling the same Xcode project for iPhone and iPad with different xib files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xib

I would like to know if it's possible to compile the same Xcode project for both iPhone and iPad, automatically changing the xib file according to the platform. The project will contain both xib files. If this is possible, how can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Universal application which contains both kind of application supporting.

Create new Xcode project > Window based application in that select Universal from drop down menu.

it will provide you two different files one for iphone and another for ipad.

and check this [link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html) to know every thing about you question.

Comment: The problem with universal app is it create two different app delegates for each device which is kind of unwanted if you would like to use the same code, just a different design layer front.

Comment: When I created a universal app in Xcode 4 recently it created two app delegates FooAppDelegate_ipad and _phone whichwhich both inherit from a common app delegate FooAppDelegate superclass. I've put everything I need on both devices into the superclass. This should also be possible to retrofit if your application is set up differently.